# PHP mysql update multiple row by single query SET='101' where id =1,2,3,7,9

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, where-clause, in-operator

I am trying to update rows in mysql but I have to use for loop for multiple update for single value mysql query is

```
update table set column1='100' where id =1
update table set column1='100' where id =6
update table set column1='100' where id =14
```

I am using for loop for running query multiple times with different id, I want to run single query for update all rows. Is that possible?

i want to do something like that

```
  update table set column1='100' where id=1,6,14;
```

Comment: @saharsh: Actually it is not desireable to add as many tags as possible like [whree-clause]. That does not really add anything to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **IN()** Operator

```
update table_name SET field_name='101'
where id IN(1,2,7,9)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `IN()`

```
update table 
set column1='100' 
where id in (1,6,14)
```

or `OR`

```
update table 
set column1='100' 
where id = 1 OR id = 6 OR id = 14
```